# Can't get a custom delegate method to execute

Tags: ios, delegation

I am using two view controllers (storyboards).  One is a standard `ViewController` and the other is a `TableViewController`.  I've setup a custom protocol within the `TableViewController`, a method called `didSelectWith` with two parameters, the class and a `NSString`.  It gets called within the `TableViewController` delegate method `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.

The idea is that a button from the first view controller segue's to the table view, takes the string inside the cell `textLabel.text` then returns to the first view controller.  It then dismisses the table view controller, and sets a simple label object to that string.  So far I cannot get back to the first view controller.

Here is the code from the table view controller:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class DeparmentsViewController;

@protocol deparmentsDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)didSelectWith:(DeparmentsViewController *)controller department:(NSString *)department;

@end

@interface DeparmentsViewController : UITableViewController

@property (nonatomic, weak) id <deparmentsDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

.

```
#pragma mark - Table view delegate method

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"didSelectRowAtIndexPath has executed");
    [self.delegate didSelectWith:self department:[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].textLabel.text];
}
```

Here is the code from the first view controller:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"departmentsSegue"]) {
        self.vc = [segue destinationViewController];
        DepartmentViewController
        self.vc.delegate = self;
    }
}

-(void)didSelectWith:(DeparmentsViewController *)controller department:(NSString *)department
{
    [controller dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    self.departmentLabel.text = department;
    NSLog(@"Delegate method called within ViewController");
}
```

All the necessary outlets are linked accordingly.  If more code is needed I can edit this post asap.

Comment: do NSLog to log 1. self.vc & 2. to log self.delegate

Comment: Is the prepare for segue called? Is this a push or modal segue?

Comment: and whats that DepartmentViewController line?

Comment: `DepartmentsViewController` is the `TableViewController` class.  It has a 5 cells with office departments e.g. HR Dept, Offices, Warehouse, etc...

Comment: @Wain - Its a modal segue